# Cloud Object Storage S3: AccessDenied Error when calling GetObject operation from specific servers

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli, object-storage

I was trying to fetch a document from S3 bucket on IBM Cloud Object Storage and I get access denied error. I was able to upload an object successfully to the same bucket with same credentials. Also I get this error when I tried to download the object from some specific servers only. Is there any limitation from COS not to allow read access from specific servers/domains ?
I tried fetching documents using aws cli commands and also with the python boto3 library as well and the behavior is same.

Error:
"An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied"

**Update:**

- I tried the same boto3 module on Mac OSX(10.11.6) with the same Bucket and Key combinations and it works fine.
- I was trying my code on a RHEL 6.8 server and it breaks for files greater than 100MB. (This has both python 2.7 and 2.6, I've tried with both)
- So even decided to use the AWS CLI command to download the file, it downloads exactly 2MB and gives the (AccessDenied) message.
- So I went ahead and checked if the NodeJS (aws-sdk) module can pull something off, and to my surprise, it worked perfectly everytime for the S3 object download on RHEL 6 and Mac OSX as well.  So NodeJS aws-sdk S3 module is able to handle large downloads on RHEL 6.

So now I'm not sure what is wrong with AWS CLI and boto3 (python based apps/modules for S3) in case of RHEL 6 server.  The same code as I mentioned works on Mac OSX with Python 2.7.

AWS CLI Command used:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.xxxx.net s3 cp  s3://bucketname/filename.tar.gz ./
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your setup?  Is there anything different about the environment that succeeds vs the environment that fails? 'Access Denied' implies that the credentials supplied are incorrect or malformed.  It would also be helpful to capture an example request (via Wireshark or similar utility) to verify that the headers being sent are what we expect to see.

Comment: @NickLange Thank you for your response.  I would like to analyze the headers and packets, but I noticed the strange behavior of Python based S3 modules on RHEL 6.  I've updated the details above.  I will update this issue with further findings on connection resets and headers being used.

Just to let you know I've checked the permission on the object and it has full control for the access id I'm using, so its not a permission issue.

Comment: There have been anecdotes about issues with some Linux environments, but this is extra strange behavior.  Out of curiosity (this shouldn't really matter) but does the account have read access on the bucket?  Really the best thing to do is to get a capture to check out the headers though, just to make sure it's not defaulting to the default AWS endpoint or is unable to find your credentials.  

I'll spin up an RHEL VM and check it out though.  If you're more comfortable via email, you can reach me at nicholas.lange[at]ibm.com.

Comment: @NickLange Thanks for investigating, I will get in touch with you over email.